# Android Database Transactions Error handling

Tags: android, sqltransaction

If I am executing a set of queries using transaction, and one of the queries failed to insert/update/delete. What will happen? Will the remaining queries continue executing by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. A rollback will be performed restoring the database to its original state before the transaction began: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollback_%28data_management%29

Comment: so if i need not to rollback, i should not use transactions?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to restore the database then you should not use a transaction.